# Difference between お見舞い and 薬

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between お見舞い and 薬?
Both are translated as "medicine" by Google Translate

I guess that お見舞い is more like a treatment while 薬 is actual medicine people take

Comment: Ι get “sympathy” on Google translate web while getting “medicine” as you say on Mobile App. https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%8A%E8%A6%8B%E8%88%9E%E3%81%84%20google%20translat

Comment: @kimiTanaka this is weird. Google says it's "sympathy" in search results, but if you click on the link to GT, it translates it as "medicine". Also, sympathy doesn't fit the context (neither does "medicine")

Comment: Google Translate doesn't count as prior research effort. Look up the word お見舞い or 見舞い at least in an online dictionary before you post a question.

Comment: @Chocolate Can advise a reasonable online dictionary?

Comment: @Marat How about...   [goo辞書(プログレッシブ和英)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/73159/meaning/m0u/見舞い/), or [Weblio和英辞書](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/見舞い), or [アルク英辞郎](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=見舞い)? For more, see this list -> https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/761/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, 薬　normally refers to an actual medicine, while お見舞い　is an act of encouraging used normally when someone gets sick, but not limited to the case.

Basically お見舞い implies you see how they are going, giving a book or food to get them well and so on. It is rather an act and not necessarily a substance you can buy for a treatment at the pharmacy.

As for Google Translate, you should provide a sentence for a better translation.
Using Google Translate at work, with only one word like "decline", I get "低下 ≅ falling down" when I want to get "拒否 ≅ turned down".

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thank you. I do not remember the exact phrase, but it was somebody coming to a hospital for this